# What label to use in `deps` for `bazel` rule `proto_library` to be able to use `google/protobuf/timestamp.proto`?

Tags: bazel, proto

I have a `.proto` file in which I'd like to `import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";`

The build fails, though, with `google/protobuf/timestamp.proto: File not found.` I'm assuming it needs `deps` to be specified for the `proto_library` `bazel` rule but don't know exactly what label to use.

Answer (score 0):

The following from https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/issues/1820 works:

```
proto_library(
    name = "proto_library",
    srcs = glob(["*.proto"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "@com_google_protobuf//:timestamp_proto",
    ],
)
```